# SQL Server: Hierarchy recursive CTE with no anchor

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy, common-table-expression

I'm able to generate a hierarchy with a recursive CTE but I have always made use of an anchor... a top level record with some top level indicator (parentID IS NULL).  I would like to build a hierarchy that doesn't necessarily have a defined anchor.  I have a many to many reference table with a parentID and a childID.  Any parent can be a child and vice versa (avoiding circular reference of course).  I'm thinking this would be more of a bottom-up approach as opposed to top-down.  Thoughts?

Comment: I'd like to see a sample of what you have so far. Maybe examples of the structures being used and attempt you are currently working on. Here is a [good place](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ecfd/13) to add examples for people to play with.

Comment: If you try to use recursive CTEs then they would run forever.  Well, except that MAXRECURSION is set to some different value.  I suspect you need a graph walking algorithm that keeps track of the nodes already visited.  I'm not sure how to implement such a beast using CTEs.

Comment: If I'm working with a single childiID and supply the childID, this query will at least build the bottom-up hierarchy:  with c as (
  select 0 as lvl,a.parentid,a.childid
  from dbo.ParentChild a where childid = 1
    union all
  select lvl+1,b.parentid,b.childid
  from dbo.ParentChild b
  join c on c.parentid = b.childid)
select distinct * from c
order by lvl,parentid,childid;

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't necessarily have a defined anchor". Do you mean you don't want to specify "where childid = 1" in your CTE?  Could you just use WHERE ChildId NOT IN (SELECT ParentId FROM ParentChild)?

Comment: *‘Any parent can be a child and vice versa (avoiding circular reference of course).’* – If there's never a circular reference in your data, then there *must* be at least one item without a parent.

Comment: I see your point Andriy, but I think that maybe I was hoping to use this method for something that it doesn't quite do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't build a recursive query using CTE without having at least one anchor member and one recursive member.

While a recursive CTE is used to generate a hierarchy , the problem in this case is that the data in the table does not represent a hierarchy, for hierarchy is a type of a directed acyclic graph , therefore it must have one element (the hierarch ) which is superior to all of the other elements.